# Build HTMLTable from C# Serverside with InnerHtml string

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmlcontrols

I am trying to loop through my client side Html table contents on my c# server side.  Setting the Html table to `runat="server"` is not an option because it conflicts with the javascript in use.

I use ajax to pass my clientside html table's InnerHtml to my server side method.  I thought I would be able to simple create an `HtmlTable` variable in c# and set the `InnerHtml` property when I quickly realized this is not possible because I got the error `{"'HtmlTable' does not support the InnerHtml property."}`

For simplicity , lets say my InnerHtml string passed from client to server is:

```
string myInnerHtml = "<colgroup>col width="100"/></colgroup><tbody><tr><td>hello</td></tr></tbody>"
```

I followed a post from another stack overflow question but can not quite get it working.

Can someone point out my errors?

```
string myInnerHtml = "<colgroup>col width="100"/></colgroup><tbody><tr><td>hello</td></tr></tbody>"

HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(myInnerHtml);
System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
table.RenderControl(hw);

for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < table.Rows[i].Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        // get cell contents

    }
}
```

Comment: Standard way dealing with Html in C# is to use HtmlAgilityPack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the HTMLAgilityPack. I found it a lot more readable and manageable for diverse situations.

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml("<html><body><table>" + innerHtml + "</table></html></body>");

    foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("//tr"))
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("td"))
            {
                var divExists = cell.SelectNodes("div");
                if (divExists != null)
                {
                    foreach (HtmlNode div in cell.SelectNodes("div"))
                    {
                        string test = div.InnerText + div.Attributes["data-id"].Value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps,

```
string myInnerHtml = @"<table>
                              <colgroup>col width='100'/></colgroup>
                              <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                         <td>hello 1</td><td>hello 2</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                          <td>hello 3</td><td>hello 4</td>
                                    </tr>
                               </tbody>
                               </table>";
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 ds.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(myInnerHtml)));

 var tr =    ds.Tables["tr"];
 var td =    ds.Tables["td"];

  foreach (DataRow trRow in tr.Rows)
     foreach(DataRow tdRow in td.AsEnumerable().Where(x => (int)x["tr_Id"] == (int)trRow["tr_Id"]))
         Console.WriteLine( tdRow["tr_Id"] + " | " + tdRow["td_Text"]);


output
=========================
//0 | hello 1
//0 | hello 2
//1 | hello 3
//1 | hello 4
```

Comment: Thank you for the well thought out answer, but I also need to retrieve information such as attributes and sometimes there is an element within the cell.  I think the HtmlAgilityPack is going to be the way to go!

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack for HTML parser is cool. Above code is an only native resolve.